# Enviar variable de Visual Basic a PHP

Tags: php, vb.net

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto, donde "leo" (con Visual Basic) el serial del disco duro de la PC del usuario, lo guardo en una variable y la envío a una página php. He resuelto el problema enviándolo por el método Get, sin embargo, deseo enviar el dato de una forma más segura, es decir, en la que no esté visible al usuario. ¿Existe algún modo de hacerlo? , agradecería mucho su ayuda.

El código (en Visual Basic) que tengo es el siguiente:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text


Public Class Form1

    Function MDhash(ByVal password As String)
        Dim md5 As MD5 = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
        Dim result As Byte()
        result = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password))
        Dim strBuilder As New StringBuilder()
        For i As Integer = 0 To result.Length - 1
            strBuilder.Append(result(i).ToString("x2"))
        Next
        Return strBuilder.ToString()
    End Function


    Private Sub btnSalir_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSalir.Click
        Dim salir As Integer

        salir = MessageBox.Show("Desea salir", "ADMINISTRADOR", _
           MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)

        If salir = 1 Then
            Close()
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnIniciar_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnIniciar.Click
        Dim disco As New  _
         System.Management.ManagementObject( _
         "Win32_PhysicalMedia='\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0'") 'Código para saber serial físico del Disco Duro'

        Dim value As String = MDhash(disco.Properties("SerialNumber").Value)
        Process.Start("http://localhost/proyecto/index.php?" & value)
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: yo estoy buscando lo mismo pero de c# a php. buena iniciativa

Comment: en este hilo te dicen como hacer un POST a un server https://stackoverflow.com/a/6108680/1423096